# Display Content of URL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a site where I serve up random content (text, images, etc).

I have created a link that displays the mysql record id of the content encoded in the url (e.g. mysite.com/country-query.php?id=23).

My problem is that when the page loads, the url is alright, but the page is just blank.

Can you help?

below are the codes:

mysite.com/country-query.php:

```
<?php

    define ('HOSTNAME', 'hostname');
    define ('USERNAME', 'username');
    define ('PASSWORD', 'password');
    define ('DATABASE_NAME', 'database_name');

    $db = mysql_connect(HOSTNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD) or die ('I cannot connect to MySQL.');

    mysql_select_db(DATABASE_NAME);

    $query = "SELECT country_id, iso2, short_name, long_name, iso3, numcode, un_member, calling_code, cctld FROM table_name ORDER by rand() LIMIT 1";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<p>", "<b>", "Short Name: ", "</b>", ($row['short_name']), "</p>";
        echo "<p>", "<b>", "Long Name: ", "</b>", ($row['long_name']), " ", "<b>","Calling Code: ", "</b>", ($row['calling_code']), " ", "<b>", "ccTLD: ", "</b>",($row['cctld'])," </p>";
        echo "<a href='action.php?id=$row[country_id]'>NEXT COUNTRY</a>";
    }

    mysql_free_result($result);
    mysql_close();

?>
```

'action.php' is where the url is displayed and the page content *is supposed* to show. Here is what I have in its code:

```
<?php

    $id = mysql_escape_string($_GET['country_id']);

    define ('HOSTNAME', 'hostname');
    define ('USERNAME', 'username');
    define ('PASSWORD', 'password');
    define ('DATABASE_NAME', 'database_name');

    $db = mysql_connect(HOSTNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD) or die ('I cannot connect to 
MySQL.');

    mysql_select_db(DATABASE_NAME);

    $query = "SELECT country_id, iso2, short_name, long_name, iso3, numcode, un_member, calling_code, cctld FROM table_name WHERE country_id = '$id' ";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<p>", "<b>", "Short Name: ", "</b>", ($row['short_name']), "</p>";
        echo "<p>", "<b>", "Long Name: ", "</b>", ($row['long_name']), " ", "<b>", "Calling Code: ", "</b>", ($row['calling_code']), " ", "<b>", "ccTLD: ", "</b>", ($row['cctld'])," </p>";
    }

    mysql_free_result($result);
    mysql_close();

?>
```

Actually, loading mysite.com/country-query.php first loads a random country, *but* the link on that page *shows* the id of that country *already* loaded, so what i'm trying to achieve here is to first of all load a landing page for mysite.com/country-query.php and then load the content of the link showing on that page in action.php

Thanks.

PS: there is a beginning php tag in the first line of the first code if it's not showing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change in action.php

```
$id = mysql_escape_string($_GET['country_id']);
```

to

```
$id = mysql_escape_string($_GET['id']);
```

**OR** in country-query.php

```
echo "<a href='action.php?id=$row[country_id]'>NEXT COUNTRY</a>";
```

to

```
echo "<a href='action.php?country_id=$row[country_id]'>NEXT COUNTRY</a>";
```

it seems you got confused with the names of parameters